# Using Phonegap storage(sqlite/websql) in ember js model

Tags: ios, sqlite, cordova, ember.js, models

I am building my first IOS app using PhoneGap, Sqlite/WebSQL (for storage) , and Ember js MVC framework.

This is what i am doing in my app:

1. While my app runs initially, I populate all the db tables in Sqlite,
2. All my server (using REST API) to retrieve all the records of user, and store the details in table.

Now I dont know **how to populate this sqlite records in ember js store** (to use it in ember models) or **is there any adapter to use sqlite db in ember js**.

I think ember js uses browser's local store (not websql)/Fixture data/REST API.

I can use the REST Adapter. but my app would run mostly on offline.The initial sync only needed the internet connection with server. I have to use the sqlite tables. if it is possible to use sqlite table with ember model please give any example codes.

I am new to all these technologies. I don't have any clear ideas about this. Please help me and let me know if I have done anything wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a special adapter for Ember Data, designed for webSQL. You should try [ember-websql-storage](https://github.com/eltiare/ember-websql-storage). It hasn't been updated for a couple of months, but it could serve as a start.